# How to hide vertices...but not object mesh...?

Tags: modeling

New to Blender 2.8.  Working on a Blender Guru Anvil tutorial.  How do I hide multiple vertices, but keep the object mesh visible?  Andrew seems to get this to work in 2.7, but it's not working for me in 2.8.  See 3rd image attached.

In Edit mode, I'm selecting the top vertices (orange), and I click "H"...the vertices and mesh both get hidden...not the vertices alone.

Thx!

M

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you need to see, exactly. The mesh is made up of vertices. Hiding them will remove the mesh. do you want to hide your mesh cage and only have the Subdivision Surface visible? Cause, that you could do with the Edit Mode Toggle on your Subdivision Surface Modifier.

Comment: This is expected behaviour ..It's a shame, IMO, that Blender works with proportional editing, not proportional (soft) _selection_, which would be more flexible and more powerful. The only way to prevent proportional editing from affecting a region is to hide it. As I recall, this is what happens in the anvil tutorial? You could retain a separate copy of the whole mesh , for visual comparison..

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys.  I've attached a 3rd image of the result that Andrew gets from B 2.7.  He's able to hide the top vertices for Proportional Editing...but the mesh object remains visible for eyeballing the proportional editing result.  Andrew doesn't make a second copy of the object.

Comment: Alternatively if there's a way to "lock" some vertices (prevent them from moving) in proportional mode without hiding them that would answer the real question (see also the answer below by @RobinBetts) being asked (this could be an XY Problem)

Answer (score 3):

Quite right ..  it works the way shown in the tutorial in 2.7 with these settings in the modifier:

[image]

..but it doesn't in 2.8:

[image]

.. which I would classify as an annoyance... there's always a chance there's a setting someone knows which makes this work?

Comment: I'm still at the stage where I'm finding modeling _much_ slower and more awkward in  2.8.. I'm giving it a few months, and a release, before I come to any conclusions about whether that's the interface, or my inexperience in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can un-toggle **"Optimal Display"** in the **Subdivision-Modifier** and use the **wireframe mode** ("Z" + "4"). This shows the wireframe even for the hidden vertices. (Using Blender 2.91).

[image: Modifier Properties]

This gives a similar visualization as in the tutorial.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and Chris's answer doesn't work in **Blender 3.2** (sorry, I can't comment on his answer)

I think it's because **GPU subdivision has to be disabled** first, and a simple workaround to do so is to enable Auto Smooth on the mesh (in the Object Data Properties tab):

[image: Auto smooth]

Then a message about GPU subdivision appears in the modifier:
[image: Subdivision modifier message]

And then **unchecking Optimal Display** does the trick.

Maybe there is another simpler workaround but I don't know about it. Anyway it would still be useful to have a proper way to proportionaly edit such a mesh without hiding any part of it.